# Is QIAPI 1 a scam?

Tags: pharmacology, photosynthesis

I find it strange that there isn't a wikipedia article on a drug that allegedly modulates human photosynthesis. I thought I might get a virus from some of the sites selling it, but others seemed decently official. I couldn't find any logs about it but there seems to be a lot of papers supporting the claims of its developers. The only testimonials I found were in spanish and I wasn't sure if they were real. Anyone heard about this stuff?

Comment: Regulating human photosynthesis? This is nonsense since humans don't do photosynthesis. Additionally it is unclear what you are asking about, so please add some references.

Comment: Based on what you are saying, yes. It is a scam.

Answer (score 2):

## Total Fraud

It's not true.  As things stand now, it is absolutely impossible for human beings to photosynthesise.  If you want a rather technical quote from D. C. Smith and E. A. Bernays:

> A survey of modern associations in which protists or invertebrates are hosts shows that very few of the many species of photosynthetic microbes are adapted to an endosymbiotic existence. None occurs as intracellular symbionts in animals structurally more complex than cnidarians and platyhelminths. Photosynthetic symbionts are not usually capable of being the sole food source for hosts because they do not provide a balanced diet; most hosts therefore retain holozoic feeding. Interactions between hosts and intracellular symbionts are complex, and have to include mechanisms for inducing release of photosynthate from symbionts as well as controlling symbiont cell division. Possession of symbionts imposes a measurable cost on hosts. For the great majority of animals, the costs of adapting to herbivory or other forms of nutrition are probably less than that of hosting photosynthetic symbionts, especially when the need for exposure of a large surface area to light is borne in mind. Once hosts become multicellular, it is virtually impossible for any photosynthetic symbionts they possess to evolve into organelles because they are restricted to specific host cell types.

Otherwise, the simple link is: http://www.bbc.com/future/story/20120906-will-humans-ever-photosynthesise.

Short answer: no complex organism truly uses photosynthesis to produce its energy because of the major loss in efficiency of gaining energy from the sun on a multi-cellular level.  Too, the amount of energy that a human being needs for survival is so massive that we would have to have leafy protrusions all over ourselves to collect enough energy to make any difference whatsoever.

Comment: Two things: 1. Is this drug about photosynthetic symbionts? If not, your answer does not fit the question. 2. I am unsure if your short answer is correct. Plants use photosynthesis to create a carbon source for "producing" (rather making it available to them) energy in cellular respiration. Accordingly, photosynthesising humans would not need to convert all their energy from photosynthesis but rather supplement their carbohydrate uptake internally. Don't get me wrong, I also think this is a total fraud. Still, I am not convinced by this argument.

Comment: Sure, that's valid, @AlexDeLarge.  I'd just encourage you to read the article on BBC that I shared.